# UniqueEntity don't check with update

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

With **Doctrine** and **Symfony 4.1** I create `User` entity with `UniqueEntity`

```
/**
 * User
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields = "email",
 *     message = "email.already_taken"
 * )
 */
class User {
    ...
```

- When I register (`INSERT`) the error is triggered : **good**
- When I update (`UPDATE`) user **with another exist email**, I have error : **not good**

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE user SET email = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["user22@me.world", 14]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'user22@me.world' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74'

Why `UniqueEntity` do not test the update ?

Comment: Are you using the symfony forms?

Comment: Yes I use symfony form :)

Comment: Could you edit you question with the snippets of the controller and form?

Comment: Wait try this `fields={"email"}`

Answer (score 2):

you can add groups to the constraint `groups={"new", "edit"}`. Then use this groups in forms like described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/form/validation_groups.html)

Comment: How we do this for API's?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try validate entity before flush?  https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

```
$errors = $validator->validate($updatedUser);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $errorsString = (string) $errors;

    return new Response($errorsString);
}
```

Errors should contain information that user already exist.

Answer (score 0):

For annonation you have to add Lifecycle Callbacks and add Doctrine UniqueConstraint

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints{@UniqueConstraint(columns={"email"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields = "email",
 *     message = "email.already_taken"
 * )
 */
class User {}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreatedAtValue()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

more information https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html